# Unique keys mean they are primary keys?

Tags: class, database-design, uml

A booking is made by a single customer and can make several bookings. Each room in .a booking can be occupied
by one or two customers. A customer can occupy several. rooms. A meal in a
booking is assigned to a table through the tableNumber attribute. **The attribute
combination name and telephoneNumber is unique**  and the attribute roomNumber is
unique.

Does unique key means its a primary key?
Does this mean that both name and telephoneNumber are primary keys?

[image]

**ADDITIONAL QUESTION:**

Can a same key be a foreign key and a primary key in a table?

Comment: A unique key means it is... unique. That makes it a candidate key and an ideal primary key, but that doesn't _have_ to be that way.

Comment: So it means that its not necessary for all unique keys to be a primary key? Possibly only of them might be a PK right?

Comment: Only one of them _can_ be a primary key @aayat, it's impossible to have more than one on a table.

Comment: On a single table? Yes.

Comment: Is it considered a composite key then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does unique key means its a primary key?

No. First of all, every key is unique, therefore saying "unique key" over just "key" is redundant. All keys in the same table are logically equivalent, but for convenience and historical reasons we single out one of them and call it "primary", while the rest are called "alternate".

> Does this mean that both name and telephoneNumber are primary keys?

No, there are no two keys here (much less two *primary* keys). There is only one composite (aka. "compound", "complex") key, comprised from two fields, that also happens to be primary.

Whether that's a *good* key is another matter...

Comment: Thanks I get it now.It is considered as a composite key.

Answer (score 0):

nope, an unique attribute only refers that the attribute has an unique value, which wont be duplicated in any other row of the table. It could be a primary key, but you have to indicate it in a relational design.

Some important points from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key)

- A table can have at most one primary key, but more than one unique key.
- A primary key is a combination of columns which uniquely specify a row.
- One difference is that primary keys have an implicit NOT NULL constraint while unique keys do not. Thus, the values in unique key columns may or may not be NULL (and in fact such a column may contain  <strike>at most one NULL fields</strike> . Because NULL is not an actual value (it represents the lack of a value)

Comment: The **"at most one NULL fields"** is wrong. You can have as many Nulls as you want. (Only SQL-Server has this weird behaviour, "only one NULL in a Unique column", which is against the SQL standard.)

Comment: @vivoconunxino i have an additional question.Can a same key be a foreign key and a primary key in a table?

Comment: yes, why not? for instance in relations n:n for tables A and B, when you need an extra table C to relate an instance of A with many instances of B and vice versa. You need two fields, foreign keys to each table, and both can form a composite primary key. In other case, when there is only one primary key for a table A and its also a foreign key referencing another table B... well, you can do it, but I think you could also add all the fields from the table A to the table B directly in a simpler way.